# Graph The Solution Of First Order Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> 1. Graph all of the solutions of $y'=-\frac{x}{y}$
>
> 2.find the value of $x_0$ and $y_0$ such there is one and only solution, defined in the area that includes $x_0$ such that $y(x_0)=y_0$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$

$$\frac{ydy}{dx}=-x$$

$${ydy}=-xdx$$

Integrating both parts: $$\frac{y^2}{2}=-\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$

$$y^2=-{x^2}+k$$ whereas $k=2c$

$$y=\pm\sqrt{k-x^2}$$

If I raise both side in the power of 2 and get a circle, I am changing the graph?

Should it be just a graph of a square root stating in y=k and a mirror graph for the negtive square root?

Answer (score 1):

You found all the real solutions expressed on the form the equation: 
$$x^2+y^2=k$$
with $y\neq 0$ (due to the term $\frac{x}{y}$ in the ODE).
This implies $k>0\quad\to\quad k=R^2$
$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$
So, the graph is an infinity of circles with a common center $(0,0)$ and any radius $R$.

Writing $y=\pm\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ changes nothing in the real domain.

But you cannot draw an infinity of circles. Don't you forgot in the wording of your question to mention a condition which allows to determine a particular value of $R$, hence to draw only one circle ?

Comment: After I graph the solutions I need to find $x_1$ and $y_1$ such there is only one solution

Comment: To do that, you must have a requirement given in the wording of the problem. One cannot help you if you don't write down the original wording of the problem, fully and exactly copied.

Comment: Sorry, added the full question

Comment: I am not sure to understand " in the area that includes $x_0$ ". If the meaning is "in the area that includes the point $(x_0,y_0)$", the equation of the circle should be $x^2+y^2=x_0^2+y_0^2$. In fact, I have some difficulty to translate the whole question. Sorry to not give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

you will get $$x^2+y^2=const.$$ can you construct the plot?

Comment: Yes, it is a circle, but am I allow to raise both side in the power of $2$? dont I lose solutions?